# Cannot boot from USB wtih ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I downloaded ubuntu 13.10 amd64 iso and used all of following methods to make a install media.

1. UNetBootin
2. Universal USB installer (from windows)

But I cannot boot from USB pen drive. Some time it just drop me in grub menu of previously installed ubuntu 13.04. Sometime it show a message "Could not open //fallback.efi: 14 ..." for a moment and then just stays there(blank screen).

How to boot from USB pen drive?

Comment: Do you have put the USB drive on the top of your boot priorities in the BIOS?

Comment: I have also tried several (other) methods under Ubuntu, but none worked other than writing it to DVD using Linux Nero, which is very strange as I've been using Live USB images for years. As a matter of fact, I've had the worst upgrading experience with 13.10, and at the end decided to stick with 13.04.

Comment: I have the same problem too.

Comment: Ditto. I see that message, then a selection menu with "Try...", "Install..", "OEM...". Selecting any of the options leads to a blank screen.

Comment: Try using YUMI from here > http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if your USB drive is bootable.

From Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick :

> Notes about bootability
>
> Most but not all USB pendrives are reliable for booting, even many of
>   the slower ones, and they are much cheaper, and should be OK
>   particularly for regular read-only live drives (without persistence).
>
> Some computer hardware and some operating systems have issues with
>   certain ports. And some USB pendrives just have issues also. Some of
>   them cannot be used for booting. They are made to be mass storage
>   devices, and have not exactly the same electronics and firmware.
>
> Some pendrives that did not work are shown in this link. The brand
>   name does seems to make a difference. This user is not the only one
>   who likes 32GB Sandisk.

Were you able to boot using 12.04 or from a CD?